# Saving PNG as GIF with .NET looks horribly speckled

Tags: .net, image, png, gif

My simple code takes me from this PNG [image] to this GIF [image] which isn't acceptable. I know GIF isn't the best format but I have to fit in with the current situation.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Dim oImage As Image = Image.FromFile("c:\whatever\temp.png")
oImage.Save("c:\whatever\temp.gif", Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
```

I also want to resize the image (shrink it a bit) but that looks even worse. I assume I need to do something with colour palettes, encoders, P mode versus RGBA.....but my Google-fu seems totally weak and I have found nothing!

If anyone can point out my stupidity with some handy VB.NET or C# that would be wonderful, thank you.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but perhaps blowing the image up (as early as possible) can improve the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is adaptively generate a 256-color palette that allows you to reproduce the original image as faithfully as possible.

There is an excellent article (containing code) to do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479306.aspx#colorquant_topic5). Grab the `OctreeQuantizer` and then it's as simple as the example code:

```
   var quantizer = new OctreeQuantizer(255, 8);
   using (var quantized = quantizer.Quantize(image))
   {
       quantized.Save(target, ImageFormat.Gif);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. Amazing how writing a GIF requires 200 lines of code, and BMP, JPG, PNG need just 2!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to find an optimized image palette for the input image.

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479306.aspx

NB: I know you're looking for a .NET based answer, but it might still be worthwhile to check out [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org). It gives you a lot of control over conversion options. There's even a .NET wrapper, though I haven't used it personally: http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/